# Completion status of HTML5 download

Tags: javascript, html, download

I have a javascript function that downloads a file to the local disk. This works fine. The issue is how to get notified when the download has completed or failed. I tried adding an event listener to the `<a>` element but that was a dead end (i.e. the event never fires). My question boils down to is there an event should I be listening for? The current code is:

```
    var doIt = function(fileName, url) {
        var hyperlink = document.createElement('a');
        hyperlink.href = url;
        hyperlink.target = '_blank';
        hyperlink.download = fileName;
        hyperlink.addEventListener("load", function(){
            alert("Done");
        });

        var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
            view : window,
            bubbles : true,
            cancelable : true
        });

        hyperlink.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
        (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(hyperlink.href);
    }
```

Thanks

LJ

Comment: simple: you cannot. there is no event, changed property, or call to make that would yield this information. you need to use the backend to watch for failed downloads, and push a warning out to the client if that occurs. that's likely more trouble than it's worth for a small UX improvement.